# How to delete text after 3rd line in multiple files

Tags: windows, plaintext, text-processors

I'm looking for a way so I can delete lines in text files after a specific line.

for example, a file contains 5 lines. I want to delete lines after the third line. see,

- Line 1
- Line 2
- Line 3
- xxxxxx
- xxxxxx1

here, I want to keep first 3 lines(line 1, line 2, line 3) and delete remaining 2 lines(xxxxxx, xxxxxx1) and automatically save that text file. I want to do this to multiple text files. Want to delete every line after the 3rd line in every text file inside a folder.

Any way to do this using notepad++?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello again, the way your question was [written here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/software-to-delete-lines-in-a-text-file) is fine and asking here how to accomplish this task with Notepad++ are both on-topic respectively, however, asking additionally for software recommendations here is off-topic at SuperUser.

Comment: This may be a bit confusing but on SE we try to narrow down questions so again asking for Software Recommendations belongs on Software Recommendations and asking for instructions on how to use software to complete a task is (in most cases including this one) on-topic at SuperUser. Asking a question that includes **both** of these questions on one site is off-topic as a part of it does not belong on the site.

Comment: Lol you are the same person who said same thing when i asked same question on softwarerecs.stackexchange isn't it? there mentioning notepad++ was off topic and here notepad++ is on topic and asking about software is off topic.. are you following me? lol

Comment: and i deleted my post there and posted here. again, here you are.

Comment: I try and stay active on both SuperUser and Software Recommendations. I saw that there were two duplicate questions from what looked to be the same user - no, I'm not following you.

Comment: and i deleted it because you told me it's off topic there and I can ask here. So asked same question here. Anyway if this is off topic, you can edit it the way you like

Comment: I [edited your question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/31505/revisions) removing the part, "or any way to do this using notepad++?" which then made it on-topic on Software Recommendations. Again, your original question really including two questions, one of them making it off-topic. You can undelete your answer on Software Recommendations, it's now on-topic and if you remove the, "Any windows software for this?" part here on SuperUser- it will be on-topic here.

Comment: Again, "Any windows software for this?" = Software Recommendations; "or any way to do this using notepad++?" = SuperUser; you just can't have both those questions wrapped up in one question

Comment: And btw, I don't think we can say it's fully off topic. Because if you read my question again, you can see, i didn't specifically asked for any third party software. I just said "windows software". It can be any software, may be an inbuilt text editor like wordpad++.  Until i say "any third party windows software", I think my question will not fall under "off topic" category.

Comment: This question is off-topic because you are asking us to suggest software that can do what you want. If you restructure your question to ask **how** to do what you want with a specific software it can stay. Otherwise, it will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: As i said in my previous comment, if somebody is not asking for any third party software, but may be an inbuilt windows feature or software, still it's off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like quite standard text operation for a number of Linux tools (don't mind the technical incorrectness), GNU sed being one of them. Until Bash/Ubuntu comes out for Windows 10, you can use something like [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) which I tested to work for the below command.

```
sed -i '4,$d' *
```

Would delete all lines starting from the 4th line in all files in the directory you are in.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for this. It worked but there's an issue. After it delete lines, previous lines are added together. If there's a paragraph or space between first  lines, those are gone after doing this. I want to keep all lines/rows. How to do it? please help

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without installing software but instead creating a simple batch script. Here's a script that will do what you want:

```
@echo off > NEWFILE & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
set/p D=delete all after what line?
set N=
:main
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (file.txt) do (
set/a N+=1
if !N! leq !D! echo.%%a
) >> NEWFILE
```

Where `file.txt` is the actual file. When you execute this script, it will ask you what line to delete after, simply say `3`. Copy the above code and paste it in a `.bat` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i want to do this deletion inside folders and sub  folders. want this deletion in every file inside lot  of folders. Not file by file.. So can i do it by this method? What changes should i make? thanks in advance.